# Add $ symbol to column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add $ symbol to column values and convert the column values to western number system

**Dollars**

4255

25454

467834

**Expected Output:**

$ 4,255

$ 25,454

$ 467,834

**My Query:**

```
select ID, MAX(Date) Date, SUM(Dollars) Dollars, MAX(Funded) Funding from Application
```

Dollars is the int datatype and needs to be changed.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why would `34255` become `$ 4,255`, `23454` become `$ 25,454`, and `7834` become `$ 467,834`? The numbers themselves are different in all three examples, so it's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: Updated my post. My fault.

Comment: you can convert datatype as 'money'

Comment: `declare @a int

set @a=12032323

select '$'+cast(@a as varchar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that. Converting from `money` to `varchar` with style 1 adds thousand separator:

```
declare @value int = 4255
select '$ ' + replace(convert(varchar(100), convert(money, @value), 1), '.00', '')

-- output: $ 4,255
```

If you process the data from SQL Server in any application, formatting is much easier to do in the code though.

Comment: But how could I sum the column values?

Comment: I'm trying this.. select ID, MAX(Date) Effective_Date, SUM(Cost) '$ ' + replace(convert(varchar(100), convert(money, Cost), 1), '.00', '') Cost, MAX(Funded) Funded from Application

Answer (score 0):

Hello basing on your output you can approach like this also

```
declare @table Table (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @table (ID) VALUES (4255)
INSERT INTO @table (ID) VALUES (25454)
INSERT INTO @table (ID) VALUES (467834)
SELECT  '$' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(id AS MONEY),1),LEN(id)+ 1) from @table
```

Thanks